# .select undefined method for main:Object (NoMethodError) Ruby

Tags: ruby, select, syntax

Trying to create a method to remove single space elements from an array if there's a single space element next to it (no double spaces). When I run the below I get this error:

ex5.rb:5:in `block in remove_double_spaces': undefined method`array' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  Array

I'm guessing this is a variable scope issue? How can I call the array itself within the select method?

My logic attempted below (select all elements of the array unless it's a blank element and the next element is also a blank).

```
def remove_double_spaces(array)
  # p array.index('w') works fine here.
  array.select { |value| value unless (value == ' ') && (array(array.index(value) + 1) != ' ') }
end

remove_double_spaces([" ", " ", " ", "w", "h", "a", "t", " ", "s", " ", "m", "y", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "l", "i", "n", "e", " "])
```

Comment: You get _"undefined method 'array'"_ because of `array(...)` – that attempts to call a method named "array" (which doesn't exist). Maybe you wanted `array[...]`?

Comment: oh my gosh embarrassing! haha thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the error just replace `array(array.index(value) + 1)` with `array[array.index(value) + 1]`.

However the solution will still be incorrect. The method `index` of an array returns the index of the **first** object in `array` such that the object is == to `value`. In case of duplicate elements in `array` there will be an error.

I'd recommend rewriting your method as

```
def remove_double_spaces(array)
  array.join.squeeze(' ').split('')
end

remove_double_spaces([" ", " ", " ", "w", "h", "a", "t", " ", "s", " ", "m", "y", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "l", "i", "n", "e", " "])
# => [" ", "w", "h", "a", "t", " ", "s", " ", "m", "y", " ", "l", "i", "n", "e", " "]
```

Comment: Very very helpful. Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this instead.

`array.map(&:squeeze)`